# Broadcast method with Express.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a problem with `Express.io`: I try to create a chat but I am not able to use the `Broadcast` method.

No error message, but nothing happens.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express.io')
    , index = require('./routes/index.js')
    , http = require('http')
    , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  //configure options
});

app.http().io();

app.get('/', index.index);

app.io.route('ready', function(req) {
    req.io.broadcast('newUser');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

**user.js**

```
io = io.connect();

io.emit('ready');

io.on('newUser', function(data) {
    console.log("New user !!");
});
```

**Error 2**

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://tchat.aws.af.cm/socket.io/1/websocket/n8Jm9Q7YYL8YdPRN4dxU' failed: Unexpected response code: 502
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.io.broadcast` broadcasts to all connected clients except the client associated with the request. You should use `app.io.broadcast` to broadcast to all connected clients.

See the example given : https://github.com/techpines/express.io/tree/master/examples/broadcasting

Comment: Yeah it works but it's very long... And I got an error message! See above.

Comment: Are you deploying your app on cloud ? This error is received when cloud servers do not support websockets. Try to set transport as io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);